# Console error with Google Plus and "Help spread the word"

Tags: civicontribute, social-media

I was testing a contribution form today and noticed an error in the console on the thank you page. I'm guessing it is related to the Google Plus portion of the "Help spread the word" section, but am not certain. The site does also have a Google Plus URL set as rel="Publisher" using the Metatag module (Drupal).

If I leave the page open and the console open, this error just keeps recurring again and again:

**Refused to display...in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'**

[image: Refused to display...in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN']

What would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a local issue; if you clear your browser's cookies the error should go away.